# How to load URL on WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am trying to load URL on WKWebView which contain the CSV file.

When I tried it loading normally it was giving me an error: '**The file format is not supported / it might be corrupted**'.

Even mobile safari is also giving me the same error.

Then I tried using MIME type with the following method of WKWebView:

```
   try! Data(ContentsOf: bulkUrl)

   webView.load(data, mimeType: "text/csv", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: bulkUrl)
```

It works but giving me plain text.

Same thing I tried it with UIWebView its opening CSV file in the correct format.

I am not getting why WKWebView is not able to open the same file. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your url?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Can't share URL due to security reasons. but when I tried to create URL using gist.github.com the URL is opening on WKWebview, with normal load URLRequest.

Comment: But MIME type is not working its giving plain text. I will let you know once I find out the solution.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First of all you need to import

```
import WebKit
```

Following code is enough to open URL with WKWebView

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: <#AnyRect#>)
let link = URL(string:"https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/239/")!
let request = URLRequest(url: link)
webView.load(request)
```

Answer (score 17):

Use -

```
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!))
```

Answer (score 8):

For Objective-C:

1. Goto Target -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embed content
2. Add Framework **"WebKit.framework"**
3. Open your file and add `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>`

Implement code in the function that you want to load `WKWebView`:

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 5):

First, import

```
import WebKit
```

Create Outlet of your WKWebView

```
 @IBOutlet var webload: WKWebView!
```

And, Put Below code in your viewDidLoad() method & wherever you want in your custom Function etc..

```
 let web_url = URL(string:"https://stackoverflow.com/users/6824665/dhaval-gevariya")!
 let web_request = URLRequest(url: web_url)
 webload.load(web_request)
```

Answer (score 4):

Select Target -> General -> Linked Framework and Libraries -> click on + symbol -> search for webKit.framwork -> add

```
import WebKit
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!))
```