# When I tap the image I want to go to the URL

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I am trying that when I press the image it takes me to the link

I have this:

```
class CoverPillCell: TableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imagePill: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var imagenButton: UIButton!
```

this contains variables that later in the load function call the remoteconfig

```
    height = CGFloat(promoPill?.image_height ?? 0)
    width = CGFloat(promoPill?.image_width ?? 0)
    target_url = promoPill?.target_url ?? ""
    position = promoPill?.position ?? 0

    if enabled == true {
        enabled = ((promoPill?.enabled) != nil)
    }
    //This is what I'm trying to when tap go to the target url which is configured on the remote config
    if imagenButton.isUserInteractionEnabled == true {
        self.imagenButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapPill(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

And in the IBAction I'm trying this:

```
  @IBAction func tapPill(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let promoPill = getPromoPill()
    
    target_url = promoPill?.target_url ?? ""
}
```

Comment: And what's your current code doing? You want to open a WKWebView? Or open Safari?

Comment: @Larme I want to openWKWebView

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load URL on WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628954/how-to-load-url-on-wkwebview)

Comment: @Larme It might work, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I am trying to click on the image that is in a cell to open the link, this link comes from remoteconfig

Comment: It's unclear. I gave you a related question with answer to open a link into a WKWebView. It's up to you to adapt it from `target_url = ` and use it, no? What's your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) link can help you

You have to do something like this ->

```
let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
```